# MAUI ListView animation time

Tags: maui

When I add items to a ListView, there is some default animation that takes about 1 second for a fade in animation to complete. Is there a way to reduce this or not use it at all so that you can get an instantly populated ListView?

Comment: `there is some default animation that takes about 1 second for a fade in animation to complete.`  I did a test on windows, but I couldn't find the animation you mentioned. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I've set up a bare project here: https://github.com/hootyjeremy/ListViewLagTest

If you look at the MainPage.xaml and MainPage.Xaml.cs, I have just one ObservableCollection attached to a ListView. I get mixed results when clicking the "Add Line" button here. Sometimes it is immediate and other times it is laggy. If you wait a few seconds between adding, you may notice the laggy animation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the laggy animation even I waited a few seconds.  How is your test equipment performing?

Comment: Ah. I don't know why it's happening on my machine then. I'll try some other things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) iOS platform-specific controls whether row animations are disabled when the `ListView` items collection is being updated. It's consumed in XAML by setting the `ListView.RowAnimationsEnabled` bindable property to false:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ... ios:ListView.RowAnimationsEnabled="false">
            ...
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Alternatively, it can be consumed from C# using the fluent API:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
...

listView.On<iOS>().SetRowAnimationsEnabled(false);
```

For more information, check document: [ListView row animations on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/listview-row-animations?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am trying to do this on Windows but I can't seem to substitute "Windows" for "iOS." I guess this is only possible on iOS?

Comment: Yes, above code is for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For windows (WinUI) I used a custom handler/renderer, which you can see below :

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;

namespace NGT.CustomViews;

public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            this.List.ItemContainerTransitions = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask me a question and I can expand if you need me to.